# How to read and write data from multiple databases by using spring batch update?

Tags: spring

I am working on spring batchupdate ,I search on google I didn't find any solution for my problem.

**I have two databases(MySQL,ORALCE) I want to read data from mysql and write into oracle by using batch update** .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is unclear.

You can first read the data from MySQL with one Spring JdbcTemplate object initialized with MySql data source, and then use another JdbcTemplate object, initialized with Oracle data source, to write the data.

If you want to do it in one transaction, you will have to use distributed transactions/XA libraries, such as Atomicos, and Spring distributed transaction manager. See here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html for details on Spring integration with distributed transactions libraries.